# PHP function duplicating data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a comment section with MySQL and PHP. But, for some reason, whenever I refresh the page, the data gets duplicated. This happens every time I refresh the page.

Example

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

It shouldn't be doing this, but it does. I think it has something to do with the `setComment()` function, but I'm not sure.

index.php

```
<?php
    include 'dbh_comments.inc.php';
    include 'comments.inc.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Comments</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="comment_styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
    echo"<form method='POST' action='".setComment($conn)."'>
            <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='Anonymous'>
            <textarea name='message'></textarea><br/>
            <button type='submit' name='comment_submit'>Comment</button>
        </form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

comments.inc.php

```
<?php

function setComment($conn) {
    if(isset($_POST['comment_submit']) && isset($_POST['message']) !== '') {
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, message) VALUES ('$uid', '$message')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}

function getComments($conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['message'];
    }
}

getComments($conn);
```

Comment: As others have suggested this is most likely a refresh and re-post issue.  However your action attribute should equal the url that you want your form data to submit to. A user after filling out the form and submitting it will then be taken to that url.  Perhaps you are thinking that upon submitting that form the function setComment will be fired?  Currently it is called whenever the form gets displayed.

Comment: @Progrock, You are right, there is a mistake in form action it must be url in stead of function.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you are right, the problem is there:

```
<?php
    echo"<form method='POST' action='".setComment($conn)."'>
            <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='Anonymous'>
            <textarea name='message'></textarea><br/>
            <button type='submit' name='comment_submit'>Comment</button>
        </form>";
?>
```

function `setComment` is called everytime you visit page and save new row to DB

Comment: It may be called every time the page is visited.  But there is a guard before the insertion.

Comment: yea but page isn't redirected after post so post is set if page is reloadead after submit

Answer (score 0):

That's because how the web works, if you POST to a page and then refresh the page, the POST data is... well, POSTed again. Your browser is probably also warning you about that every time you refresh, right?

So what you want to do is to redirect the user back to the original form when you handle the POST, so..

```
if($_POST['message']) {
   ... save message in sql...
   header("Location: /back_to_Somewhere.php");
   exit();
}
```

It is very good practice to always redirect the user somewhere else after you POSTed.

Comment: Where would I add this statement?

Comment: Where you call setComment, or even inside setComment itself (at the beginning)

Comment: The OP is calling setComment at the wrong moment in their script to handle a redirect.  As redirects must happen before any page output.

Answer (score -1):

You are including the comments.php file at the top of the file.
In the comments.php file you are calling a function (`getComments($conn)`), which echo's out data.

This gets printed on the page at the very top, where the file is included.

Comment: Comments are echoed out before any html, which doesn't sound ideal.  But what has that got to do with duplicate rows being inserted into the database upon page refresh after a submission?

Answer (score -1):

Please check how many records are inserted in your db. `I hope your application unset the $_POST array after inserts.` And you are not refreshing the page clicking refresh button. if yes, when alert comes you must not be pressing confirm. if yes you are inserting duplicate data.

Well, in simple words I was saying the same, your app is inserting duplicate data. If you post data and do not `unset($_POST)` array it will insert data every page loads, as your insert query is inside `if(isset($_POST['comment_submit']) && isset($_POST['message']) !== '')`. Better unset it after your insertion is done.